# Implementing the Android Zoom Out Page Transformer for a ViewFlipper

Tags: android, animation, android-viewpager, viewflipper

I was looking for an animation to use for my view flipper and found this awesome page transformer animation on the Android Training page:

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

However, this is implemented using a ViewPager.PageTransformer and I'm using the newer ViewFlipper in my code. Has anyone figured out how to create such an animation using the ViewFlipper and ObjectAnimators? Just to explain what I've done so far:

- I have an AdapterViewFlipper that gets populated with Fragments depending on user interactions.
- The user can "flip" through these fragments by swiping on the ViewFlipper. This is done using a GestureDetector (OnGestureListener).
- The onFling method defines the animation for the ViewFlipper

The last point is where I need to define the animation and this is where I'm lost.

Any ideas or help?!